# Text overlapping in PosColumn inside row while using "esc_pos_bluetooth" for thermal printing in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, thermal-printer

I'm facing a small issue regarding designing while using `esc_pos_bluetooth` for thermal receipt printing

Everything is working fine. I'm just unable to figure out how to move the text to the next line if there is not enough space in the `PosColumn` in `row`. All the text of the row is overlapping each other.

```dart
final ticket = Ticket(paper);


ticket.row([
   PosColumn(text: "x3", width: 1),
   PosColumn(text: "Shan Haleem Masala Mix", width:7),
   PosColumn(text: "135.0", width: 2),
   PosColumn(text: "420.0", width: 2),
   ]);
```

I'm using the below code for reference.
https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_bluetooth/blob/master/example/blue/lib/main.dart

Package Link:
https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_bluetooth

[image]

Comment: Maybe this article can be applied. [Why does my text not wrap? #4128](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4128)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know about the `Flexible` but unfortunately, it is not the normal flutter column. It is the `PosColumn` which is defined in the `esc_pos_bluetooth` package, which is used for printing text on receipt

Comment: Then look for an issue in esc_pos_bluetooth and contact the author if you don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you still have the same issue, but I can suggest one thing to check the paper size you are setting in your code. I think you have set it to

```
ticket = Ticket(PaperSize.mm80);
```

and for your small printer you should `mm58`

```
ticket = Ticket(PaperSize.mm58);
```

I believe this will help you to expand better the first row for table header.
And for wrapping the text, I am still suffering from the same issue.